# how to pass urls from some file through docker-compose to vuejs/angular apps?

Tags: angular, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

Recently I started working with docker-compose in order to make vuejs and angular applications to be deployable into development environment. During that time the target was to make all the api urls in vuejs and angular applications to be injected through some external config/json-config(eg. usr/share/html/env-config.json) file into docker-compose and then into application.

I managed to inject a file of urls into the docker container using docker compose. But how can I access those values as baseurls for various apis in vuejs or angular applications? That's the main challenge I am facing.
Has anyone an idea how I can access values from config/json-config file available in the docker container to be used in a vuejs app?